# Direct2D custom effect: size/memory limitation?

Tags: windows, shader, effect, direct2d

I'm working on a direct2d custom effect to convert YUV420 to RGB.
The codes are based on the Visual Studio built-in sample: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Direct2D-custom-image-7a1f2cb5?SRC=VSIDE

The changes are basically: 1) removing all effect properties, 2) setting input number as 3 (for planar Y, U, V, respectively); and 3) the pixel shader.

The HLSL code is quite simple:

```
float4 color;
color.r = InputTexture0.Sample(InputSampler0, uv0.xy).r - 0.0625f;
color.g = InputTexture1.Sample(InputSampler1, uv0.xy).r - 0.5f;
color.b = InputTexture2.Sample(InputSampler2, uv0.xy).r - 0.5f;

static const float3x3 yuv2rgb = {
    1.1643828125f, 1.1643828125f, 1.1643828125f,
    0.0f, -0.39176171875f, 2.017234375f,
    1.59602734375f, -0.81296875f, 0.0f
};
color.rgb = mul(color.rgb, yuv2rgb);
color.a = 1.0f;

return color;
```

The effect functions well when the input bitmap has width about <=480 (U,V bitmap with width 240).

However, the result image goes really weird when the size is larger than mentioned above: The green,blue components becomes 0.0f and the result image looks composed by 2 colors, red&black.

I'm pretty convinced that the shader still works well by 2 observations:

1) The image render result is normal if I call DrawImage block by block, with the block width <=480. 

2) I add

```
color.g = color.b = color.r
```

before the shader return. It turns out that and the image with width <=480 turns black&white, while over-sized image still looks red&black.

What happened?

Comment: This was also [posted to a Microsoft Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7ec839e7-11e8-49e8-857d-083a50ab6a46/direct2d-custom-effect-sizememory-limitation?forum=vsga), and has an answer there.